# magento 1.9 add custom product image type

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

how can I add a custom product image type in the image gallery?

e.g, see `banner_landing` type in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

found a great tutorial for it. I'll paste it here since I didn't find any other reference on SO and might be useful to the community https://www.pixafy.com/blog/2012/12/adding-a-fourth-image-position-to-the-admin-for-a-magento-product/

Comment: Thank you for sharing this great tutorial man. :)

Answer (score 4):

You need create new install script.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('catalog_product','new_image_attribute',
    array (
        'group'             => 'Images',
        'type'              => 'varchar',
        'frontend'          => 'catalog/product_attribute_frontend_image',
        'label'             => 'New Image Attribute',
        'input'             => 'media_image',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'           => true,
        'default'           => '',
        'class'             => '',
        'source'            => ''
    )
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

To use this type of image in your product page, call the image like this:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'new_image_attribute')->resize(400,300); ?>
```